# Flow: declare type for nested objects

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I got a very simple question about giving an type with flow to an object, here is a code sample :

```
type Test = {
  a: string
}

const t = {
  test_object1: {
    a: 'foo'
  },
  test_object2: {
    a: 'bar'
  }
};
```

How can i add the **Test** type to my **test_object**s if they are them self inside an object ?

I tried :

```
const t = {
  test_object1: {
    a: 'foo'
  } : Test,
  test_object2: {
    a: 'bar'
  } : Test
};
```

or

```
const t = {
  test_object1<Test>: {
    a: 'foo'
  },
  test_object2<Test>: {
    a: 'bar'
  }
};
```

but none are working.

Comment: To set annotations inline you need parentheses around the value: `({a: 'foo'} :Test)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
type Test = {
  a: string
}

const t: {
  test_object1: Test,
  test_object2: Test,
} = {
  test_object1: {
    a: 'foo'
  },
  test_object2: {
    a: 'bar'
  }
};
```

```

source: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-object-type-syntax

Answer (score -1):

You have to type the whole object, I don't think you can do "nested" typing:

```
const t = { ... } : { test_object1: Test }
```